# Android how do I read resource file within project

Tags: android, filereader

I'm trying to read the file DictionaryWords in the image below

[image]

How do I read in this file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can move the `DictionaryWords` file to your `assets` folder, which will then cause it to be included in your `.apk`. Then you can open it with something like:

```
context.getAssets().open("DictionaryWords")
```

Comment: Well, that's the general case where you need an instance of a `Context`. As it turns out, `Activity` is a subclass of `Context` so you may only need to call `getAssets()`, if you're calling it from within an `Activity`.